# How do I make this an asynchronous hook?

Tags: feathersjs

How do I make this function wait for the promise to resolve in each nested for loop so I can set the relations for each collection? The exercise names are printed after the context log.

```
        find: [
            function (context) {
                context.result.data.forEach((workout) => {
                    workout.exercises.forEach((exercise) => {
                        context.app.service('exercises').get(exercise.exerciseId).then((data) => {
                            exercise.name = data.name;
                        });
                    });
                });

                console.log(context.result.data[0]);

                context.dispatch = context.result;
                return context;
            }
        ],
```

**Relations are:** workout has many exercises and exercise has 1 name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When iterating over several asynchronous tasks [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is your friend:

```
async function (context) {
    await Promise.all(context.result.data.map((workout) => {
        return Promise.all(workout.exercises.map((exercise) => {
            return context.app.service('exercises').get(exercise.exerciseId).then((data) => {
                exercise.name = data.name;
            });
        });
    });

    console.log(context.result.data[0]);

    context.dispatch = context.result;
    return context;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Daff

Comment: Can you quickly explain to me why this works? Does map return a promise?

Comment: It returns an array of promises (returned by `context.app.service('exercises').get`) and `Promise.all` waits for them all to resolve before resolving with an array of the results.